# Formula for a disease spread in java timer

Tags: java

I have a formula that sets the initial speed of the virus spread and I want it to increase as the number of infected people increases. So I created a formula inside java timer but when I start my program the speed is constant.

```
 void setInfected() {

        Virus virus = new Virus(this);
        spreadSpeed  = (int)( (density + density) +
                (climate * virus.coldResistFactor) + (climate * virus.heatResistFactor) +
                (economy * virus.medResistFactor) + (tourism * virus.airEffFactor) +
                (humidity * virus.touchEffFactor) + (dead * virus.plagueFactor));
        deadSpeed = (int)( (density * virus.lethalFactor) );
        spreadTimer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(!Game.isPaused) {
                    infected += spreadSpeed;
                    population -= infected;
                    dead += deadSpeed;
                    infected -= dead;
                    spreadSpeed = population > 0 ? spreadSpeed + ( infected / population ) : 0;
                    deadSpeed = population > 0 ? ( deadSpeed * ( infected * virus.lethalFactor ) ) / population : 0;
                    System.out.println("infected: " + infected);
                    System.out.println("dead: " + dead);
                    System.out.println("population: " + population);
                }
            }
        }); 
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            spreadTimer.start();
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `spreadSpeed` is an int. Because of this any division operation you do with it gets rounded down.

Since you don't cast `(infected / population)` to an int, they both proboably are int. Meaning the division will also be rounded down which will result in a 0 until the infected are more than the population.

To fix this issue, you could make spreadSpeed a double instead of an int and cast the population in the division to a double to force the division to use floating point numbers and not integers. For this to work you also need to cast the spreadSpeed to an int when removing people from the population/adding people to the infected.